# Importing data from postgresql with Dask

Tags: python, postgresql, dask

So I have a large (7GB) dataset stored in postgres that I'm trying to import into Dask. I'm trying the read_sql_table function, but keep getting ArgumentErrors.

My info in postgres is the following:

- database is "my_database"
- schema is "public"
- data table is "table"
- username is "fred"
- password is "my_pass"
- index in postgres is 'idx'

I am trying to get this piece of code to work:

```
df = dd.read_sql_table('public.table', 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost/my_database?user=fred&password=my_pass', index_col='idx')
```

Am I formatting something incorrectly?

Comment: what's your exact error message?

Comment: As an aside, `dd.read_sql_table()` expects the schema to be passed as a separate argument, i.e. via read_sql_table('table', ..., schema='public') in your case, or at least that's what I get when I try to reproduce this. However, since you're getting an ArgumentError and not a NoSuchTableError, there must be some other problem as well. Could you post the full error message?

Comment: If you want to get answers, before starting a bounty I'd suggest editing to give more details and show what you have tried.  Please provide a [mre] so I can answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was finally able to figure it out by using psycopg2. The answer is below:

```
df = dd.read_sql_table('table', 'postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:fred@localhost/my_database', index_col = 'idx')
```

Additionally, I had to create a different index in the postgres table. The original index needed to be a whole separate column. I did this with the following line in Postgres:

```
alter table table add idx serial;
```